# NativeScript Installation Error "spawn ENOTDIR"

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, installation, nativescript

Unable to install NativeScript via command `npm i -g nativescript` under Node v8.9.4

Traceback:

```
$ npm i -g nativescript                      
/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/nativescript -> /Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/tns -> /Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns

> fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> nativescript@3.4.3 postinstall /Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node postinstall.js

spawn ENOTDIR
Failed to display command help { Error: Unknown command 'post-install-cli'. Try '$ tns help' for a full list of supported commands.
    at Errors.fail (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:125:28)
    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:134:21)
    at HelpService.<anonymous> (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/services/help-service.js:140:26)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/services/help-service.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  name: 'Exception',
  message: 'Unknown command \'post-install-cli\'. Try \'$ tns help\' for a full list of supported commands.',
  stack: 'Error: Unknown command \'post-install-cli\'. Try \'$ tns help\' for a full list of supported commands.\n    at Errors.fail (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:125:28)\n    at Errors.failWithoutHelp (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:134:21)\n    at HelpService.<anonymous> (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/services/help-service.js:140:26)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/services/help-service.js:4:58)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)',
  errorCode: 127,
  suppressCommandHelp: true,
  proxyAuthenticationRequired: false }
+ nativescript@3.4.3
added 708 packages in 14.695s
```

**Output of** `tns post-install-cli --log trace`:

```
$ tns post-install-cli --log trace
Loading extensions.
execFile: /usr/local/bin/sdkmanager/platform-tools/adb "help"
Error while executing '/usr/local/bin/sdkmanager/platform-tools/adb help'. Error is: spawn ENOTDIR
Exec uname -a 
 stdout: Darwin B52.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Tue Jan  9 20:12:05 PST 2018; root:xnu-3248.73.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

 stderr: 
Exec npm -v 
 stdout: 5.6.0

 stderr: 
Exec node-gyp -v 
 stdout: v3.4.0

 stderr: 
Exec xcodebuild -version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Error while executing xcodebuild -version: Command failed: xcodebuild -version
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Exec gem which xcodeproj 
 stdout:  
 stderr: ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library xcodeproj

Error while executing gem which xcodeproj: Command failed: gem which xcodeproj
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library xcodeproj

Exec pod --version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: pod: command not found

Error while executing pod --version: Command failed: pod --version
/bin/sh: pod: command not found

Exec null version 
 stdout:  
 stderr: /bin/sh: null: command not found

Error while executing null version: Command failed: null version
/bin/sh: null: command not found

spawn: /usr/local/bin/sdkmanager/tools/emulator "-help"
Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/child-process.js:58:30)
    at Promise (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/child-process.js:66:39)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.spawnFromEvent (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/child-process.js:65:16)
    at SysInfo.<anonymous> (/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/sys-info-base.js:194:59)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/sys-info-base.js:7:71
Initializing analytics statuses.
Analytics statuses:  { TrackFeatureUsage: 'enabled', TrackExceptions: 'enabled' }
spawn: node "/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/services/analytics/analytics-broker-process.js" "/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/bootstrap.js"
```

Comment: Can you execute `tns post-install-cli --log trace` and send us the output to be able to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: @anthares appended in question.

Comment: Solved the issue by setting 

    export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"
and

    export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"  

after installing the android-sdk from homebrew via `brew cask install android-sdk`

Comment: Running `tns doctor` raised error :

    spawn EACCES
    Failed to display command help { Error: Unknown command 'post-install-cli'. Try '$ tns help' for a full list of supported commands.

which can be solved by going to installation directory of native-script which in my case was
 `/Users/rayman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/nativescript/`

now run
`chmod +x ./setup/mac-startup-shell-script.sh` giving it executable permissions.
`tns doctor` works fine and completes setup.